# How can I force a floating keyboard programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard, ipados

Is there a way to programmatically enforce a keyboard to be floating when it appears? I'm trying to implement this on an iPad app for a `UITextField`. The reason is that in floating mode it presents the decimal pad, which is what I want.

Comment: There should be an option on the TextField, in Interface Builder, to set the keyboard input type.

Comment: Cheers - I've already set that - the issue is that on the iPad it presents a normal keyboard and I don't want that - I just want it to float to the decimal pad automatically and force it in that state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force the floating keyboard, unfortunately.